# difference between root and ALL PRIVILEGES

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I want to create a user with restricted grants compared to root. 
If I do

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'non-root'@'localhost';
```

am I assigning all the same privileges as for the `root` user? Or are there some privileges in the `root` user that are not included in the `ALL PRIVILEGES` privilege?

For example: Is the new user able to create other users?

Otherwise I'll explicitly list the grant I want but this question is more for my learning.

Comment: *Or there are some privileges in the root user that are not included into the "ALL PRIVILEGES"?* TRUE. There is a lot of privileges not relative to database/table. For example, FILE privilege...

Answer (score 3):

To answer your question:

> Is the new user able to create other users?

The answer is NO, the new user is not able to create other users nor grant/revoke privileges to other users.

If you want to create a root similar user you must issue the following statement:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'non-root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing special about the user `root`.

`root` is normally granted `SUPER` and `WITH GRANT OPTION`, and doing it `ON *.*` thereby providing all the nasty things you should give to non-root users.  But all this is a convention.

Often an application is given

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES
    ON db_app.*          -- limited to the app's database
    TO app@'...'         -- '%' is scary, but may be necessary
                         -- but no `WITH GRANT OPTION`.
```

This would give you "admin" as much privilege as normally given just to `root`:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO admin@'%'         WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO admin@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Note that `%` does not include `localhost`.  This is an important security point.

It is probably better to give only this to `root` (or your `admin`):

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

That is, not also exposed to the outside world.  This gives you a layer of protection by forcing `root` to first log into the server, and only then can he get into mysql with full privileges.